# MySQL multiple CHAR_LENGTH()

Tags: mysql

I would like to run an SQL SELECT that returns rows where the match and profile fields total more then 300 characters. I've tried line below but it doesn't work - how can chat length be added to make a total and only allow over a certain limit.

```
SELECT match,profile FROM matches WHERE SUM (CHAR_LENGTH(match),CHAR_LENGTH(profile)) > 300;
```

thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
SELECT match, profile 
FROM matches 
WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(match) + CHAR_LENGTH(profile) > 300;
```

Answer (score 1):

`SUM` is an [aggregate function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html), used for adding values in the same column across multiple rows.  To add values in different columns of a single row, just use `+`.